# Cant create aws ec2 Certificate. Body must not contain a private key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I'm using puttygen to create the three required ppk. Certificate CertificateChain and private key. After that I convert the three ppk files to pem files.

Then using the tutorial on aws I write the following lines in the ec2 terminal:

```
$ aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name ExampleCertificate
                                    --certificate-body file://Certificate.pem
                                    --certificate-chain file://CertificateChain.pem
                                    --private-key file://PrivateKey.pem
```

Then I receive the error:

```
An error occurred (MalformedCertificate) when calling the UploadServerCertificate 
operation:

Certificate body is invalid. The body must not contain a private key.
```

I've tried to use different keys. I'm not really sure what to do. I thought I followed the steps correctly. I'm at a loss here.

Comment: When creating the encryptions. The private key doesn't have a password associated with it. The other two do have a password with it.

Comment: Does the Certificate.pem file starts with --BEGIN CERTIFICATE--- and ends with --END CERTIFICATE---? 
You can refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html#server-certificate-troubleshooting for the format.

Comment: *"The other two do have a password with it."*  That really doesn't sound right, because the other two (certificate and chain) are public documents that an SSL-enabled web server will hand out to every web browser connecting to them.  There's not a reason for them to be password-protected.

Comment: It does, I posted another comment below

Answer (score 0):

If you were after uploading a keypair for an ec2 server, the process I use is

- Log into the AWS Console and create a new Keypair *server-default*
- Save the private key somewhere safe like a Password Repo
- Open putty gen, open the private key and hit the save *Public Key* option and save it somewhere useful like `/temp/server_pub.pem`
- Run the AWS Cli to upload the public key for the Keypair

```
aws ec2 import-key-pair --region us-east-1 --key-name server-default --public-key-material file:///temp/server_pub.pem
```

Comment: I do have the begin and end certificate tags for the certificates. The problem is creating them in the first place. I wasn't following the right  steps which is why I'm having the issue.

Are there any helpful guides for this? openSSL doesn't seem to be too helpful. I don't know why I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.

Comment: Followed this guide to the teeth:   https://smartnets.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/create-certificate-chain-and-sign-certificates-using-openssl/     and now I'm getting this error... An error occurred (MalformedCertificate) when calling the UploadServerCertificate operation: Unable to validate certificate chain. The certificate chain must start with the immediate signing certificate, followed by any intermediaries in order. The index within the chain of the invalid certificate is: 2

Comment: I usually create the certificate from the AWS Console by going to Ec2 > Key Pairs > Create Key Pair